# How to sort lines multiple times?

Tags: linux, perl, bash, solaris, disk

I have to figure out the physical disk number that belongs to each device in an OmniOS (Solaris 10) storage array. I can get the list of devices by

```
cfgadm -al | grep disk-path | cut -c 6-21 | tr 'a-z' 'A-Z'
```

where the output could look like

```
5000C5005CF65F14
5000C5004F30CC82
...
```

So my idea is to write a script where I `dd` each device and watch the leds, and then enter the number of the led that flashed. As there are leds on both sides of the storage array, I need to be able to run the script multiple times, and for each time I enter a disk location, I shouldn't have to enter it again.

My current idea is to loop over the list of device names I get from the above command and then do something like this

```
system("dd if=/dev/dsk/c1t${device}d0p0 of=/dev/null bs=1k count=100");
print "which led flashed: ";
my $disk = <STDIN>;
chomp $disk;
system("echo $disk $device >> disk.sorted");
```

which would produce lines like these

```
21 5000C5005CF65F14
09 5000C5004F30CC82
...
```

where I have seen led 21 flash in the first case and seen led 9 in the second case. There are 70 disks.

**My problem**

I can not come up with a good idea how I can write a script which can be run multiple times, and for each time it is run it will not destroy my previous values I have entered.

Any ideas how to do this?

I am prototyping it on Linux.

Comment: Can you clarify "it will not destroy my previous values I have entered"?  In the perl code you wrote, each time it is run, the new values will be appended to the 'disk.sorted' file and the previous ones should not be destroyed.

Comment: Actually also not a bad idea, but I would switch to use $f as the output file name and write the $n into it. And you need the output redirection with >> to append to the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Script 1

```
rm -f /tmp/a/*
rm -f /tmp/b/*
mkdir -p /tmp/a
mkdir -p /tmp/b

for f in $(cfgadm -al | grep disk-path | cut -c 6-21 | tr 'a-z' 'A-Z'); do touch /tmp/a/$f; done
```

Script 2

```
controller="c3t"

for f in /tmp/a/*; do
    dd if=/dev/dsk/$controller${f##*/}d0p0 of=/dev/null bs=1k count=100
    echo "Which led flashed? Press RET to skip to next"
    read n
    if ! [ -z $n ]; then echo $controller${f##*/} > /tmp/b/$n && rm -f $f; fi
done

cat /tmp/b/*
```

Script 3

```
for f in /tmp/b/*; do
    echo $f
    dd if=/dev/dsk/$(cat $f)d0p0 of=/dev/null bs=1k count=100
done
```

Answer (score 0):

For each run of your skript, write the output into a different file, say `out.1`, `out.2`, and so on. Afterwards run

`sort -k +2 out.*`

you will have all results for one disk one after another. The sort will sort the contents of all files given according to the second column, which is the disk id.

Comment: The filename should be the disk number the content the device name, or what do you mean? I don't understand your idea.